# How do you open a URL in Xcode using sprite kit with swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, rating

How do you open a URL in Xcode using Sprite Kit with the programming language swift. For example having the user go to rate your game on the app store or taking the user to your website.

Comment: Do you want to open the URL in safari or do you want to show the website inside the app ?

Comment: detecting a pattern here

Answer (score 0):

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
```